# How to track funds in SF

Tags: custom

In Salesforce I would like to be able to track what we internally call our 'External Funds', for certain opportunities we require to use these External Funds to pay for service outside our scope. (but they do not need to go against opportunity value)

External Funds are usually replenished every quarter or whenever they have been exhausted by our accountant. 
Is there a functionaly in Salesforce where we can track this amount and add/edit it? as well displaying it in a field in opportunities showing how much of the fund its used (if any).
I would like the fund to be viewable in Dashboards to see how much is remaining and possible even a report showing which opportunities have utilised the fund.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to create a custom object with a couple of fields 1 being 'Quarter Amount' and the other being 'Amount Remaining'. So every quarter you will just create a new record with the "Quarter Amount" filled in and the Available funds field will start at the full amount. You can put a trigger on the opportunity that will deduct the amount from Amount remaining every time an opportunities 'External Funds' field is populated? Also you can make sure you don't exceed the available amount as well as show the external funds available when an opportunity is created. Something of that nature sound about right?

EDIT: You can also report on that custom object via a dashboard and show the available funds as well as opportunities utilizing the funds this quarter if you wanted. You can add a "time stamp" wf on the opportunity that will stamp a 'back-end' field to show when the funds were requested on the opportunity or when they were utilized depending on your companies sales process. So you can know exactly when those funds were used on actual sales.

Comment: I can kind of see how this can all work, but is there a way I can see the remaining balance when creating the opportunity? (or at least when assigning hours)

Comment: The only way to display data referenced from another object or field in SF on a create new/edit page is by creating a VF page and overriding the new/edit buttons. It's fairly simple to create and you can create field sets that will allow you to dynamically update the VF page with out dealing with html or controllers every time you want to change stuff around. Check out this link: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create custom fields in `Opportunity` to display your `External Funds`. Were I architecting this, I would create a separate object for the External Funds which may need to be a child of another `Internal Accounting Object` (discuss this with your accountant as to how its handled on the books). You would then use look-ups for the fields that are displayed under each of your Opportunities.

Your `dashboard` for `External Funds` that shows amount used vs amount available for the quarter would need to be on the `External Funds object` not on `Opportunity`. This could be confusing whenever its replenished, especially if replenished prematurely, something you'll want to be able to indicate on your dashboard should that happen.

It would seem easy enough for your `External Funds Object` to reference the `OpportunityId` the funds used were dispensed to; allowing you to easily look-up the `Opportunity Name` to also add to your dashboard as well.

Based on projects I've worked on, that's the general approach I'd take to what you're trying to do. Workflow would seem to handle everything you're trying to accomplish. I'm not certain how these funds are dispensed, but you'll need to sort out whether this is something you'll also need to make available under `Tasks` as well as `Expenses` related to Opportunities and how to prevent that from being applied to the `Opportunity Cost` if you do.

Comment: In the `External Funds Object` would I be storing total funds available or Opportunity keys and the funds they have used?

Comment: That would depend in part on how these funds are related to other accounts. Generally speaking, I'd expect you'd be storing the `amount for each transaction` & the `related opportunityId`, the `total balance available` along with `transfers` into the account. That's what I've seen in a similar situation in an org I worked in where opps were partially funded externally by a sponsor of some kind. Hope that helps.